# Can't download file with node js request lib

Tags: node.js, request, postman

I am trying to download a file ( an csv) by using request library, this is the code I have:

```
const request = require('request');
const fs = require('fs');

request
  .get('https://orchard.vn/wp-content/uploads/woo-feed/google/csv/201803_google_shopping.csv')
  .on('error', function(err) {
    console.log(err)
  })
  .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./test.csv'))
```

And i got this error:
[image]

But it is ok when using postman

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For some websites direct http/https calls are blocked , thus you need to use a proxy server. I have put facebook.com as sample , i would recommend creating a proxy on your own.

```
const request = require('request');
const fs = require('fs');
const httpsProxyAgent = require('https-proxy-agent');
const agent = new httpsProxyAgent("http://facebook.com");
const options = {
  url: 'https://orchard.vn/wp-content/uploads/woo-feed/google/csv/201803_google_shopping.csv',
  path: '/',
  agent: agent
};

request
  .get(options)
  .on('error', function(err) {
    console.log(err)
  })
  .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./test.csv'))
```